# Sails.js REST server based on jsonapi.org specification

Tags: rest, sails.js, json-api

I need to develop REST server strictly accrding to [jsonapi.org](http://jsonapi.org/) specification and I'm not sure if there is some complex solution or even if it's easy to develop such thing.

I've found [sails-hook-jsonapi](https://github.com/IanVS/sails-hook-jsonapi/), but it looks unmaintained for some time.

I'm new to Sails and not aware of all it's features and would appreciate any help, I may missed something obvious.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Long story short - there is no way to do it out of the box with little time investment. At least for now. 
But [sails-hook-jsonapi](https://github.com/IanVS/sails-hook-jsonapi) looks like good starting point, repository seems to be active now.

I've done project prototype on loopback.io framework, because I was in hurry and loopback had better jsonapi support.

Answer (score 0):

I have needed this too. There is not anything that works yet with Sails. sails-hook-jsonapi does not work correctly. I Forked that code and am maintaining my own version of it but there are still significant attribute serialization issues with multiple records. However, it does work at a basic level. I am also working on a new project sails-generate-jsonapi-blueprints but it is not nearly ready yet.

Sails is great but can ba a royal PIA. The guys maintaining Sails have had many requests for jsoanapi.org support but I do not believe that will happen anytime in the near future. If you REALLY must have JSONapi.org format I would suggest Loopback or some other API that already has support for it out of the box.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, I take part of that back. sails-hook-jsonapi is working. I made a little change in the fork I maintain. https://github.com/NikkiDreams/sails-hook-jsonapi. Ian is maintaining the original project fork too I believe. https://github.com/IanVS/sails-hook-jsonapi

So the catch about the hook is that it hijacks every single request sent to responses/ok.js If you need something like an Authorizer that does not need jsonapi create a variant of ok.js that simply does a res.json(data) without the jsonapi-serializer being called when serializing the response.

sails-hook-jsonapi will serialize most of your data to your needs. But it still has a few limitations. Depending on the complexity of your queries these may not be an issue.

TODOs: Included request parameter handling (400 response if present)
 Links
 Top-level "self" links
 Top-level "related" links
 Resource-level "self" links
 Related resource relationship links
 Metadata links
 Pagination
 Formatting
 Non-dasherized attributes
 Sparse fieldsets